# docker-compose up exit with code 0 for react js

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, mern

I am trying to use docker for MERN project. I have created Dockerfile in both client and server, and docker-compose.yml in root folder.
I executed code **docker-compose build**. It executed without any error. Then I run **docker-compose up**, node and mongodb run successfully but react js is exited with code 0.

Dockerfile for client

```
# build environment
FROM node:12.18.2-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/ps-client

WORKDIR /opt/app/ps-client

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
# COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000


CMD [ "npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8" # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/ containers to be run
services:
  back-end: # name of the first service
    build: server # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000" #specify ports mapping
    links:
      - database # link this service to the database service

  database: # name of the third service
    image: mongo # specify image to build container from
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" # specify port forwarding

  front-end: # name of the second service
    build: client # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # specify port mapping
```

I tried **docker-compose --verbose up** only for react js, [result](https://codeshare.io/aYJP9R)

**docker container inspect b9e429** result of this command is [result](https://codeshare.io/5XgPwo)

Comment: check logs using docker logs <container name>

Comment: you can see issue here : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Comment: or just running docker image with : docker run -it <docker image name> and check working or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following options to the `front-end` service configuration in the docker compose file.

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

This should be equivalent to running the container with the `-it` options.

You can read more about the issue here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Comment: Thank you for the answer, its working now but unable to call any api, error is occuring Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/auth from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
front-end_1  | See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).              I am hitting the api from postman, its working

Comment: @KhushbooModi Inside your react app try connecting to back-end:5000/api/auth instead of localhost:5000

Answer (score 0):

Add `tty: true` to your front-end service should suffice. The full context of the issue is described at: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688 as mentioned by Teddy Sterne